Navigate to Quick Action for Object from LWC
I have an LWC that appears on a Lightning page for a standard object.  I'd like to have a button on that LWC that launches a custom action for that object.  That action is of type "Lightning Component"  I've search on it but unfortunately almost all the hits are on actions that launch an LWC and I want to do the opposite.
I messed around a bit with NavigationMixin with no luck. And I'm not sure that is the right approach.  When I put the action on a page layout and click it, it launches the aura component in a modal but the URL stays the view URL -- https://myorg-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/lightning/r/Event/00UHq00000uEzEOMA0/view.  The button just tells the script internal to Lightning to run the component in a modal.
Is there anyway to do that from within LWC?  That is, stay on the View page and launch the custom action defined for the object.
There reason I want to do this is I want more control.  I want to be able to conditionally render or not render the button that launches the action.

I'm not sure I fully understand the context. But would it not be best to have a child component encapsulate all the functionality; and this either be used by a Quick Action parent component, or used by that other component that you place on your Lightning page?

I Eventually plan to migrate all the functionality.  We have one aura component that several years old and run from the quick action on the object.  Then we have an LWC that is used in place on the page.  We want to migrate the functionality of the Aura component to the LWC but aren't there yet so we're hoping to put a button in the LWC that launches the Aura component in the context of an Action.
